# Saving data in internal storage from Trusted Web Activity when user click on button in a web page

Tags: android, sqlite, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I have a PWA and it stores data in the index DB of web browser. Whenever user clears the browser history , the data stored in the browser also get cleared. So i want to store the data in a text file in android internal storage from the browser. So i have included my PWA into Trusted Web Activity. My question is how to store file/data in the android internal storage from the web page shown in the trusted web activity.[calling android function from java script]

i have also included my PWA into Android web view. But Web view does not support background synchronization. So i have started trying with Trusted web activity. I do not want to use Hybrid App like apache cordova to access the android native functionality(storing in internal storage ).

Comment: You can create Javascript-native-interface to call Android function to do your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to access Android's internal storage from a Trusted Web Activity.